# What's the minimum safe distance from the back of a dryer to a wall?

Tags: dryer, ventilation, ducts

Let's say I have a side-venting dryer. If I don't need to run ductwork behind the dryer, how close can I safely place the dryer to the wall?

Comment: The installation manual should have the requirements. Model number?

Comment: Whirlpool WED72HEDW

Comment: What type of wall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [installation manual](http://www.whirlpool.com/digitalassets/WED72HEDW/Installation%20Instruction_EN.pdf), 5" is recommend, but 0" is allowed.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

The *minimum recommended* distance is one inch:

> Additional spacing of 1" (25 mm) on all sides of the dryer is recommended to reduce noise transfer.

The *allowable* distance [seems to be zero inches](http://www.whirlpool.com/digitalassets/WED72HEDW/Dimension%20Guide_EN.pdf).